# PySide instalação

Tags: python-3.x, instalador, configuração, pyside

Estou tentando instalar o PySide no python 3.5 (32-bit), instalei o pip sem problemas, mas não estou conseguindo instalar o **easy_install**, aparece esse erro quando rodo no cmd aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando rodo o comando 'import easy_install' no console do python, não aparece nenhum erro pra mim e quando rodo o "import PySide' da o erro 'ImportError: No module named 'PySide'"

Alguem sabe o que causa esse erro?

Comment: @zekk não deu certo aqui, coloco exatamente isso no cmd? eu coloquei com o '> ' junto e sem, e n deu certo aqui

Comment: @zekk não estou conseguindo, coloquei assim no cmd: > easy_install PySide, mas não reconhece o 'comando' PySide

Comment: Na variável `PATH` está o caminho do Python? ex: *C:\Python27\Scripts*, se não estiver coloque, aqui funciona...http://i.stack.imgur.com/dzQ36.png

Comment: Como uso essa variavel PATH? primeira vez que mexo em python

Comment: Veja: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: Qual é o local de instalação do Python no teu pc?

Comment: Estou tentando achar aqui, está instalado, mas não acho onde está a pasta python, não me atentei a isso quando o instalei @zekk

Comment: @zekk Está aqui: C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No momento **não há compatibilidade** do PySide com o python 3.5.

A compatibilidade existe apenas nas versões **[2.6 - 3.4]**